# cakePHP3 Using Entity Mutator to dynamicaly load Association

Tags: entity, cakephp-3.0, mutators

I'm in a situation where I'm using an entity with an association as a function paramater, like `doSomething($entity->setting->isactive)`. When calling `doSomething()` I can not be sure that `$entity` has its setting association loaded.

Now I wondered if I could use a mutator in `$entity` to load it, like:

```
protected function _getSetting($value)
{
    if (!$this->setting) {
        $this->setting = $this->getTableLocator()->get('Settings')->get($this->setting_id);
    }
    return $value;
}
```

It is working, but it would produce an `E_NOTICE` undefined property for trying to access `$this->setting`. Otherwise I could do the check before passing $entity to my doSomething(), but I thought using a mutator might be an elegant solution, but as it throws me a Notice I'm not quite sure if thats the case. Thanks for your thoughts on that :)

Comment: You might look at using `loadInto` instead of the longer line you have there. And you might also look at this [lazy loading plugin](https://github.com/jeremyharris/cakephp-lazyload); it's worked pretty well for me.

Comment: Thanks for the plugin link, Greg Schmidt. Looks interesting. The `loadInto` is a function of Table class, thus I don't really understand how I could use it in an entity, without loading the Table beforehand :)

Comment: Ok about the `E_NOTICE`: It seems like an entity will produce an `E_NOTICE` when you try to access its properties, like `$this->setting`, but I'm not quite sure why, when I debug the code my debugger shows the value $this->setting. I think my mutator should not try to access and set $this->setting, but instead used the passed `$value`, correct?